# Is it possible to use a HashMap key as part of the value without cloning in Rust

Tags: rust

This question is derived from the [rustlings hashmaps/hashmaps3.rs exercise](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/hashmaps/hashmaps3.rs). Here is some  standalone code that simplifies the question:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Team {
  name: String,
  goals_scored: u8,
}

fn build_add_score(team_name: String, team_score: u8, scores: & mut HashMap<String, Team>) {
  let team = scores.entry(team_name).or_insert(
    Team{ name: team_name, goals_scored: 0 });
  team.goals_scored += team_score;
}

fn main() {
  let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();
  build_add_score(String::from("My Team"), 5, &mut scores);
  println!("scores: {:?}", scores);

}
```

Trying to compile this, produces the following error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `team_name`
  --> src/main.rs:12:17
   |
10 | fn build_add_score(team_name: String, team_score: u8, scores: & mut HashMap<String, Team>) {
   |                    --------- move occurs because `team_name` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
11 |   let team = scores.entry(team_name).or_insert(
   |                           --------- value moved here
12 |     Team{ name: team_name, goals_scored: 0 });
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

There is also a suggestion to add `clone()`:

```
help: consider cloning the value if the performance cost is acceptable
   |
11 |   let team = scores.entry(team_name.clone()).or_insert(
   |                                    ++++++++
```

Is there a way to do this without cloning the value? It seems strange that in a system language striving for efficiency you would need to clone a value to use it twice in a read-only way.

Comment: You can use `Rc`, but it'd probably be best to just not include the team name in the value, and make the map `HashMap<String, u8>`. What purpose does the name serve in the value?

Comment: This is a simplified example. You can imagine that the struct will contain more values and that you might want to index several HashMaps for quick lookup and return a complete struct to the caller.